# Keep all columns when using gsub

Tags: r

I have a dataset `LonGB` which contain the following dataframe:

```
Number   City     Street    Av.Cost
1       London     Ap (U)     550
2       London     Up         450
3       London     Ar         350
4       London     Tr (M)     250
5       London     Ar         545
6       London     Sl         530
7       London     Qr         520
8       London     Re (N)     510
9       London     Ra         480
#With 58 more rows
```

I want first to remove the symbols within brackets as the code to the right does
`gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(LonGB$Street))` which gives the following tibble:

```
Street
Ap
Up
Ar
Tr
Ar
Sl
Qr
Re
Ra
#With 58 more rows
```

However, I don't want just the street column but the whole dataset just without the symbols within brackets, like this:

```
Number   City     Street    Av.Cost
1       London     Ap         550
2       London     Up         450
3       London     Ar         350
4       London     Tr         250
5       London     Ar         545
6       London     Sl         530
7       London     Qr         520
8       London     Re         510
9       London     Ra         480
#With 58 more rows
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; LonGB %>% mutate(Street = gsub("\\s*\\ ([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(Street)))`

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
LonGB$Street <- gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(LonGB$Street))
```

Comment: Minor beginner fault by myself I see. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr) ; LonGB %>% mutate(Street = gsub("\\s*\\ ([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(LonGB$Street)))
```

The following code brought by @gaut solved my task.

Comment: if my answer is satisfactory, don't hesitate to flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

```
library(dplyr)
LonGB %>% mutate(Street = gsub("\\s*\\ ([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(Street)))
```

or in base R

```
LonGB$Street <- gsub("\\s*\\ ([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(LonGB$Street))
```

You are just replacing the `Street` column.